# Application.properties location when tomcat deploys

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a war file with `application.properties` in default resources. I want to, when deploying on Tomcat, put these properties into an external folder like `/webapps/example`, not `/webapps/namewar`.

Can I configure my Maven or do something to achieve that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: In Springboot, in your main class, you can use the annotation `@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
, ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })` to define where to load the application.properties, this is the default classpath, just change it to the one you want

Comment: You can also add multiple `@PropertySource` annotations

Comment: Hi! I do not want to do that, I want to when tomcat deploys move these properties to external folder like it is doing with root folder of .war

Comment: i don't think you can do any configuration on Maven as it will come into picture only while building war and not while exploding and deploying that war. what you can do is to write a script to deploy your war on tomcat, which will copy your application properties after exploding war and then start tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven-resources-plugin's copy-resources goal to copy a file from your source tree to some directory. You need to add something like the following to your pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- you may want to choose another phase -->
            <!-- see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- outputDirectory can be absolute or relative to ${basedir} -->
              <outputDirectory>/webapps/example</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/resources</directory><!-- or whereever your application.properties reside -->
                  <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: That is doing the copy when I'm clicking on "Maven - Install" but I want to do exactly the same, but when tomcat starts with some war. Can I do?

Comment: How do you start Tomcat?

Comment: I am starting with console

Comment: Then maybe you want to write a script that first copies the application.properties file and then starts the server?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be valid.